# How do I replace an ILAsm throw with a rethrow with Mono.Cecil?

Tags: .net, powershell, mono.cecil, ilasm

I have a C# dll with a member similar to the following:

```
public void DoStuff(int i) {
    try {
        something.InnerDoStuff(i);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I figured out how to get the [throw opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.throw.aspx):

```
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\ILSpy2\Mono.Cecil.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'c:\Program Files\ILSpy2\Mono.Cecil.pdb.dll'

$dll = 'c:\Program Files\ZippySoft\Something\foo.dll'
$assemblyDefinition = [Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]::ReadAssembly($dll);

$doThingsIlAsm = (
    (
        $assemblyDefinition.MainModule.Types `
            | where { $_.Name -eq 'DoerOfThings' } `
            | select -first 1 *
    ).Methods | where { $_.Name -eq 'DoStuff' }
).Body.Instructions 

$throwOp = ($doThingsIlAsm | where {
    $_.OpCode.Name -eq 'throw'
})
```

My question is how do I replace throw opcode with a [rethrow opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.rethrow.aspx)?

Comment: Your headline asks how to "replace" the opcode, but you have asked merely how to "get" it.  Which are you interested in?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can get an [`ILProcessor`](http://www.inevitablesoftware.com/Help/Nova.CodeDOM/html/bcc83e37-b043-d81a-b959-89c58faf8a53.htm) for your method, [`Create`](http://www.inevitablesoftware.com/Help/Nova.CodeDOM/html/436fe770-c90d-8344-cdc7-1f55a46befda.htm) a `rethrow` opcode, and then use the processor's [`Replace`](http://www.inevitablesoftware.com/Help/Nova.CodeDOM/html/3cdc16bf-e4b6-be30-67ac-a291a035486b.htm) method to swap the `throw` for a `rethrow`.

Instead of immediately getting your method body's instructions, get a reference to the method body and use it to get `myMethod.Body.GetIlProcessor` as well as `myMethod.Body.Instructions`. Then you can find the throw instruction as you already are, and use the Replace method to swap them out.

This is very untested, but I think the gist of it is:

```
$throw = # your existing stuff
$il = myMethod.Body.GetIlProcessor()
$rethrow = $il.Create(OpCodes.Rethrow) # not sure about the powershell syntax for enums
$il.Replace($throw, $rethrow)
```

Comment: @JustinDearing just call the Write method on you assemblyDefinition.